# Pyspider Installation for Python 3.5/win 64 "Failed building wheel for lxml

Tags: python, lxml, python-wheel, pyspider

I'm trying to install pyspider and always got

"Failed building wheel for lxml...", It looks like the lxml is not installed properly and I've tried to download lxml-3.6.1-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#psutil. However, it looks the download link is ineffective. Could you give me some advice on how to resolve this or share me with the whl file? Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I changed another computer and download successfully. Maybe it's just a connecting issue.

Pyspider installation step:

1.python get-pip.py

2.download lxml-3.6.1-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#lxml and saved to python installation path

3.pip install (Path???)lxml-3.6.1-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl

4.pip install pyspider

5.download phantom js and copy the bin folder to environment viable

6.pyspider all

7.http://localhost:5000

In memory of my first Stackoverflow post. And I don't want to delete this post. LOL